# How can I create a new tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, faq-proposed

I want to create a new tag for trains for [my question here.](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7526/how-do-train-tracks-handle-really-cold-weather) How can I do this? Does an admin have to do it for me?

Comment: We already have [tag:railroad]]

Comment: One issue I have with the word train is that it has many different meanings. One general meaning revolves around the word to teach or to learn (to train for an event) & the other general meaning concerns a series of connected items (rail road rolling stock, train of gears, camel train, a train of thought). As hazzey implies in his comment, the railroad tag includes railroad trains.

Comment: @Fred yes it's one of the many confusable facets of English. At the time I didn't think of "railroad". There is no need to add a "train" tag, unless we want to be really really thorough and add it as a synonym to railroad.

Answer (score 1):

You need to earn enough reputation on a site in order [to earn the create tags privilege](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags).  For a beta site like Engineering, that's 150 points.  On a regular SE site, it's 300 points.

When you think a question needs a new tag and you do not have enough reputation to create the tag yourself, you should ask the question using existing tags and then leave a comment below your question suggesting the new tag that you think would be appropriate. A user who is more familiar with the site may be able to suggest an existing tag that would serve the purpose or, if no such tag exists, edit the new tag into your question.

In this case, a user with sufficient permissions has already edited your post and added relevant tags.