# Is there an earthquake tag, or can we make one?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was looking for an earthquake tag for [my new question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7568/how-can-large-bridges-be-made-resistant-to-earthquakes) but didn't find one. Can we make one?

Answer (score 3):

As described [here](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/424/how-to-create-a-train-tag), creating tags requires a certain reputation threshold. Another user has edited your question with the appropriate [seismic](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seismic) tag.

Comment: Yea i remember. By "we" I meant "the community".

Comment: @DrZ214, I don't understand what you mean. A tag is created by the first user with sufficient reputation who needs it. The community doesn't have anything to do with the tag's creation. At most, the community deals with the tag wiki. And given that there's a "seismic" tag, I don't see a *raison d'être* for an "earthquake" one as well.

Comment: I was not aware of the seismic tag. I typed in "quake" and "earthquake" and nothing popped up. I didn't think of the word "seismic". Yes I understand tag creation. I was asking for someone in the community to do it since I don't have the rep. But now I see seismic already exists and a user took care of adding it to my question, so there is no need to create the tag. Problem solved.